# access viewport pixel values in ogre

Tags: c++, background, rgb, ogre3d, ogre

I'm working on ogre project by using C++. Normally I use viewport:setbackground() but this cause whole window same colour. This time I want to load different R, G, B values for each viewport's pixel. My window is 600*600 and I have to load RGB values for each pixel. How can I solve this question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set a background you can do this:

Create a rectangle that fill all viewport

```
Rectangle2D* rect = new Rectangle2D(true);
rect->setCorners(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
rect->setRenderQueueGroup(RENDER_QUEUE_BACKGROUND);
rect->setBoundingBox(AxisAlignedBox(-100000.0 * Vector3::UNIT_SCALE, 100000.0 * Vector3::UNIT_SCALE));
SceneNode * node = sceneManager->createChildSceneNode("Background");
node->attachObject(rect);
```

Create a material and texture

```
TexturePtr texture = TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual("BackgroundTex", ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, TEX_TYPE_2D, 600, 600, 0, PF_R8G8B8, TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE);
MaterialPtr material = MaterialManager::getSingleton().create("BackgroundMat", ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);
Technique* technique = material->createTechnique();
technique->createPass();
technique->getPass(0)->setLightingEnabled(false);
technique->getPass(0)->createTextureUnitState("BackgroundTex");
rect->setMaterial("BackgroundMat");
```

Now you can copy your RGB data directly to texture framebuffer:

```
texture->getBuffer()->blitFromMemory(PixelBox(600, 600, 1, PF_R8G8B8, (void*) data));
```

**EDIT 2011-11-10**

**data** must be a valid pointer to a framebuffer of raw RGB. You can initialize it:

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[600 * 600 * 3];
```

And than write yellow directly to pixel at position x,y.

```
unsigned char* red = &data[(x + y * width) * 3];
unsigned char* blue = &data[(x + y * width) * 3 + 1];
unsigned char* green = &data[(x + y * width) * 3 + 2];
*red = 255;
*blue = 0;
*green = 255;
```

Or write directly to **texture->getBuffer()** ([Ogre API: HardwarePixelBuffer](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1HardwarePixelBuffer.html))

```
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)texture->getBuffer()->lock();
```

... write directly to pixelbuffer ...

```
texture->getBuffer()->unlock();
```

This example can be generalized for other width, length, format etc...
You can use more optimized code to find pixel inside the buffer, this is just an example.

Comment: its nice code part but I want to set different RGB values for each pixel of texture not same RGB value for whole texture. How can I do this ?

Comment: What I have explained show you how you can write directly to the pixelbuffer, so you can change what you want. Now I've added more info of how you can find a pixel giving coordinates and write to it.

Comment: according to this code you cannot assign values for each pixel. First you assign position value to *red, *blue and *green. After that you assign colour values to *red. That is, position will be disappear at *red. there is no meaning of this part unsigned char* red = data[(x + y * width) * 3];

Comment: @barzos I'm sorry, before **data** you need **&**. I've edited example code, it works fine, I've tested it. Anyway, this is more general topic than ogre, this is "how to find a pixel reference in a pixelbuffer giving coordinates".

Comment: I can generate an image from texture with this method because I checked with texture->convertToImage(). I save image to file so method is working. Hovewer I cannot set it as a background in my renderwindow. Still my created window background is black, normally image would be seen

Comment: You have to add this texture to a material and apply that material to a `Rectangle2D` that cover all your viewport (see the first block of code above).

Comment: Exactly I am doing the same thing but I cant obtain image as a background. always I see black render window